# Should I submit my CV while applying for a German student visa?

Tags: visa, germany, student-visa

During German student visa application, if I provide my CV along with my application, would it increase my chances of getting my visa, or decrease the visa processing time?

Answer (score -1):

When I applied for a student visa a CV was obligatory. If its one of the listed documents then you must send it.

Comment: From which embassy did you apply for your visa? There wasn't a requirement for me.